# Which svg elements can be child, and which cant be

Tags: svg

In html we say, the inline elements should be within the block elements.
Similiarly, is there any rule that i can use, to find out which svg elements can be child, and which cant be.

Comment: Have a look at the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html

Comment: No, there isn't such a simple rule…

Answer (score 21):

Containers that can contain graphics children are [container elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#TermContainerElement):

> [A container element] can have graphics elements and other container elements as child elements.
>
> Specifically: ‘a’, ‘defs’, ‘glyph’, ‘g’, ‘marker’, ‘mask’, ‘missing-glyph’, ‘pattern’, ‘svg’, ‘switch’ and ‘symbol’.

Any element can have a non graphical child though e.g.

```
<rect>
   <title>what the rect is</title>
</rect>
```