# Not able to append label on edge of graph in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to js & d3. I am trying to plot a graph with d3.js forced layout.
My purpose is to append labels ("XXX" & "OOO") on either sides of edges but it's not working.

Here the code snippet:

```
    link.append('svg:text')
    .attr('class', 'aEnd')
    .text(function(d) { return "XXX"; });

link.append('svg:text')
    .attr('class', 'zEnd')
    .text(function(d) { return "OOO"; });
```

Here is the complete code I am working on.

JSFIDDLE : [d3_graph_labelled_edge.js](http://jsfiddle.net/seemant/0d7en4po/138/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting a `text` element inside a `line` element is not allowed, as summed up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9227842/2898738).

What you can do is wrapping the `line` elements inside `g` containers and append the link labels to them:

```
var glink = vis.selectAll("line.link")
              .data(data.links)
              .enter().append("svg:g");

var link = glink.append("svg:line")
             [...]

glink.append('svg:text')
  .attr('class', 'aEnd')
  .text(function(d) { return "XXX"; });
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0d7en4po/168/).