# appendChild works with "g" but not with "rect"

Tags: javascript, svg

I was trying to create SVG elements in JS and append them to a "rect" element. That doesn't work, but I can append to a "g" element. I get the feeling I'm violating some rule, but I can't find anything that says it shouldn't work.

if you look at my code sample, you'll see that r2 is shown, but r1 is missing.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <svg height=100vh width=100%>
    <g id='g'>
      <rect id='r' width=100 height=100 fill='green'/>
    </g>
      </svg>
  </div>
  <script>
    function setAttribs(elem, attrs) {
      Object.entries(attrs).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        elem.setAttribute(key, value);
      });
      return elem;
    };

    const g = document.getElementById('g');
    const r = document.getElementById('r');

    const r1 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
    const r2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');

    setAttribs(r1, {
      x: 0,
      y: 100,
      height: 50,
      width: 40,
      fill: 'blue'
    });
    setAttribs(r2, {
      x: 0,
      y: 150,
      height: 50,
      width: 40,
      fill: 'red'
    });

    r.appendChild(r1);
    g.appendChild(r2);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227128/which-svg-elements-can-be-child-and-which-cant-be

Comment: It doesn’t work because a `<rect>` can’t have a `<rect>` child. Only [animation and descriptive children are permitted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect#usage_notes).

Comment: thanks. with slightly different wording I now can find that answer.  was using the wrong terminology to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that rect can have graphical children, instead try to draw on top of it
like

```
<html>
<svg height='100vh' width='100%'>
    <g id='g'>
      <rect id='r' width='100' height='100' fill='green'/>
      <rect id='r2' width='59' height='59' fill='blue'/>
    </g>
</svg>
</html>
```

also, try to use editors like https://www.svgviewer.dev/ to test things statically before attempting to make dynamic code

Comment: that seems to be true. just wish I could find the documentation that states that. How does this editor help? how would I append children in it?